# PHP modulos and items that don't equally divide

Tags: php

I have a simple foreach loop set up. I've set it up so there's a count `$count` and every four items it would insert an element containing information about the four items.

```
<?php if ($count%4 == 0) : ?>
    <div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but what if the total number of items don't equally divide by 4? What if there's 17 items? Is there a way to check what is left over?

Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what the modulo you're using is already telling you. Instead of checking it against 0, store it first, and do any required checks on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it depends what you're after really, you could do something as simple as this to put your 'Div' after the remaining elements if it didn't end on something that was `modulus 4`

```
$items = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven'];
$itemsCount = count($items);

for ($i = 0; $i < $itemsCount; ++$i) {
    echo $items[$i] . '<br/>';

    if (($i+1) % 4 === 0) {
        echo '---- Past four items explained here.<br/>';
    }
}

if ($itemsCount % 4 !== 0) {
    $x = $itemsCount % 4;
    echo '--- Past '. $x .' items explained here.<br/>';
}
```

**Output:**

```
One
Two
Three
Four
---- Past four items explained here.
Five
Six
Seven
--- Past 3 items explained here.
```

You could also chunk the array into smaller parts and do a nested loop.

```
$items   = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven'];
$chunked = array_chunk($items, 4);

foreach ($chunked as $group) {
    foreach ($group as $element) {
        echo $element . '<br/>';
    }
    echo '---- Information about the last group here.<br/>';
}
```

**Output:**

```
One
Two
Three
Four
---- Information about the last group here.
Five
Six
Seven
---- Information about the last group here.
```

If you just want to know how many you will have left over after you have split your content into chunks of 4 you can do the following:

```
$amountLeftOver = $arrayLength % 4;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "break up" your loop in loops over 4 individual items, then perhaps you should consider chunking the object (array or `Traversable`) you're iterating over:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // or $array = range(1, 10);
$chunked = array_chunk($array, 4); // 2D array, each of 4 elements, the last one might contain less elements though
foreach ($chunked as $arrOfFour) {
    foreach ($arrOfFour as $value) {
        //do stuff
    }
    echo 'processed: ' . implode(', ', $arrOfFour);
}
```

If you are dealing with something other than an array (an object implementing the `Traversable` interface in some form or another), you could convert it to an array to be safe:

```
$array = iterator_to_array($traversableObject);
```